# my security q in Facebook does not exist

Tags: facebook

i searched many times but all of sites says that it will be in settings / security tab, but it's not there! why?

> i just created my Facebook account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general Facebook support. You'll need to contact them about this, not us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like FB is not currently using security questions.  This is from FB:

If there ever comes a time where you can’t log into your Facebook account, we need ways to get in touch with you and make sure the account is yours. Here are some things you can do to help make sure you never get locked out of your account:

- Add another email address to your account so you always have a
  backup.
- Make sure you and only you can access the email addresses listed on your Facebook account. Anyone with access to one of the email
  addresses listed on your account can request a new password for your
  Facebook account. If you lose access to one of your extra email
  addresses, be sure to remove it from your Facebook account.
- Add your mobile number to your account. We can also send things (ex: a code to reset your password) to your mobile phone.
- Use your real name and date of birth on your account so we can find your timeline if you ever loose access to it.

You can find more details on this [security features page](https://www.facebook.com/help/413023562082171).

Answer (score 0):

facebook now does not offer any security questions for account safety. It uses now two-factor security model and sms authentication code. Don't go in that deeply.